# Javascript calculation for working out price depending on what is entered

Tags: javascript

I am trying to come up with a solution using JavaScript that calculates the price of something depending on what is entered. The default price is £1000 but if the quantity goes over 5.5, the price increases by £250 for each 0.1 until the total price reaches £50,000. The way I would have approached this is using an if statement however in this situation this will not be viable. Is there a way to do this using a for loop?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Post some code that you have already tried. Then someone will help you correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create situation by splitting it in two options, no need for a loop:

```
// Option 1 is the easiest, the 'normal / default price"
const thresholdQuantity = 5.5;
let price = 1000; // we set the base value

// Option 2: Only do extra work when you are past the threshold:
if( quantity > thresholdQuantity){
    // Now we want to know how many steps we differ from 5.5
    let diff = Math.floor((quantity - thresholdQuantity))*10;
    price += diff*250;
    // And now make sure we dont go too high:
    price = Math.min(50000, price);
}
```

Comment: This returns 50000. For example if I set the quantity to 6 I should get 2250 as the price but I am getting 50000

Comment: Changed max to min, was a mistake (which you could've found yourself ;) 50000 only occurs once in the code)

Comment: The exact formulae can be changed if you want something slightly different, it's the principle I'm showing